# Invalid write of size 4 in constructor

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am using Qt5. In a program that I am writing I have a class with a very simple constructor. The problem is that, when I check for problems with Valgrind, I get "Invalid write of size" at every assignment.

This is the header:

```
#ifndef RS22812_H
#define RS22812_H

#include <QObject>

class RS22812 : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RS22812(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~RS22812();
private:
    uint mode;
    Flags flags;
    QString byte2Digit(uchar byte);

signals:
    void modeChanged(uint newmode);

public slots:
    void newValue(const QByteArray &data);
};

#endif // RS22812_H
```

And the constructor definition in the cpp file:

```
RS22812::RS22812(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    mode=0;
}
```

Valgrind gives me error at both the QObject(parent) and the mode=0:

```
Invalid write of size 4
  in RS22812::RS22812(QObject*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/rs22812.cpp:4
  1: RS22812::RS22812(QObject*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/rs22812.cpp:4
  2: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/mainwindow.cpp:29
  3: main in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/main.cpp:7
Address 0x1c4ad500 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd  1: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/mainwindow.cpp:29
  3: main in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/main.cpp:7

Invalid write of size 4
  in RS22812::RS22812(QObject*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/rs22812.cpp:6
  1: RS22812::RS22812(QObject*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/rs22812.cpp:6
  2: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/mainwindow.cpp:29
  3: main in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/main.cpp:7
Address 0x1c4ad500 is 0 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd  1: operator new(unsigned long) in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
  2: MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*) in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/mainwindow.cpp:29
  3: main in /home/javi/ProgrammingProjects/multimeterGUI/main.cpp:7
```

I don't understand how such a simple assignment can lead to an error. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How do you use your class? What does your `MainWindow` constructor do? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? (Something which you should know by now, having been a member here for so long)

Answer (score 0):

After trying several things, it seems that the problem was with QtCreator. When I cleaned the project, it compiled without problems.